# Two ordered triples of distinct non-collinear points, show there is a unique motion.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

'Let $P_0,P_1,P_2$ and $P_0′,P_1′,P_2′$ in $\mathbb{E}^2$ be two ordered triples of distinct non-collinear points such that $d(Pi,Pj) = d(Pi′,Pj′)$ for all $i,j$. Prove that there exists a unique motion $T :\mathbb{E}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{E}^2$ taking $Pi$ to $Pi′$ for all $i$.' (We're assuming here that $d$ is the Euclidean metric).

I understand this idea intuitively, but am not sure how to formally prove it. Any hints are ideas on how to start are appreciated.

Comment: Are $P_i$ and $P'_j$ points in $\mathbb{E}^2$?

Comment: Apologies, yes. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: OK, then I would approach the problem as follows. The rigid motion $T$ will be a translation composed with a rotation. For the translation part, you can take the translation that takes $P_0$ to $P'_0$. Then, without loss of generality, we are in the case when $P_0 = P'_0 = (0,0) \in \mathbb{E}^2$. Since $d(P_0,P_1) = d(P'_0,P'_1)$, $P_1$ and $P'_1$ are vectors of the same length with endpoint at the origin, so there is a unique rotation about the origin that takes $P_1$ to $P'_1$, and you need to argue that the same rotation takes $P_2$ to $P'_2$ as well.

Comment: So the fact that there is a unique motion (more specifically a rotation) from $P_1$ and $P_2$ to $$P_1'$ and $P_2'$ is due to the fact that there exists a unique motion from any point in $\mathbb{B}^2$ to any other point in \mathbb{E}^2$?

Comment: Well, in the case when $P_0=P'_0=(0,0)$, $||P_1|| = ||P'_1||$, where $||.||$ denotes the Euclidean norm. So $P_1$ and $P'_1$ are points on the same circle, and I suppose you are using that rotations act transitively on circles to find a rotation that takes $P_1$ to $P'_1$. On the other hand, $(P_0,P_1,P_2)$ are vertices of a triangle, so there's a well-defined angle between the sides $P_0P_1$ and the side $P_0P_2$, say $\theta$. You can find $\theta$ using the law of cosines, for example, by solving $d(P_1,P_2)^2 = d(P_0,P_1)^2 + d(P_0,P_2)^2 - 2d(P_0,P_1)d(P_0,P_2) \cos(\theta)$ for $\theta$.

Comment: Similarly, you can find the angle $\theta'$ between $P'_0P'_1$ and $P'_0P'_2$, and because all of the other quantities in the law of cosines are equal, $\theta = \theta'$. Because rotations about the origin preserve angles between vectors centered at the origin, if $P_1$ goes to $P'_1$, then the vector that makes an angle $\theta$ with $P_1$, namely $P_2$ goes to the vector that makes an angle $\theta=\theta'$ with $P'_1$, namely $P'_2$.

Comment: Actually, I forgot one detail in the above sketch, namely how $\theta$ is oriented, and you may need to add a single reflection about a fixed axis to your rigid motion.